# Struts2 Freemarker XSS Vulnerability

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, struts2, xss, freemarker

In my application we use the struts URL tag in our freemarker templates like this:

```
<s.url action="struts-action-name"/>
```

The issue is that instead of appending the action url to the root url of the application it actually appends it to the current URL.

Say we hit `www.example.com/community/examples/xss187ba"><ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>506d1768713/career_development`, and in the ftl for that page we have a form like this:

```
<form action="<s.url action="struts-action-name"/>">
```

The rendered ftl would look like this:

```
<form action="/community/examples/xss187ba"><ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>506d1768713/career_development">
```

Which causes an alert to popup... has anyone dealt with this issue? Is this a bug in Struts or are we doing something wrong here?

The obvious fix is to use the URL tag like this:

```
<form action="<s.url value="/struts-action-name.jspa"/>">
```

On the other hand a quick search shows 2500 uses of that tag in the project and refactoring all those would not be a very fun/efficient job :(

Any help, comments or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

-Andre

Answer (score 1):

The `url` tag doesn't "append" to anything--it creates a URL relative to the application, in this case based on a configured action name. Assuming an action named "f1" and a root deployment the only thing the tag would produce is an absolute URL `/f1.action` (or `/f1' with no extension).

Given:

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",,action"/>

  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="f1" class="radios.RadioAction" method="input">
      <result name="input" type="freemarker">/WEB-INF/radios/input.ftl</result>
    </action>
...
```

The FreeMarker fragment:

```
<@s.url action="f1"/>
```

will output:

```
/f1
```

You may need to provide more info: are you using specific plugins (like Convention), etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.URLTag` and replace the exiting or add a new tag in `struts-tags.tld`.

Answer (score 0):

I do find it weird that it does not automatically url-encode those parts of the URL, as that's what I would expect it to do.
So I would consider this a bug. Maybe contact the Struts developers about this one. Most of their other tags do automatic encoding, so it's weird that this one doesn't.